# VSCode how can I use GMT timezone

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create a snipping code that includes the date in GMT zone, I was able to put the date in the snipping but how can I converted in GMT zone

date: $CURRENT_DAY_NAME_SHORT $CURRENT_MONTH_NAME/$CURRENT_DATE/$CURRENT_YEAR $CURRENT_HOUR:$CURRENT_MINUTE:$CURRENT_SECOND

Answer (score 0):

Use the extension [CommandVariable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) and the dateTime command. You have a lot of options to format your date and time